# Nonsmooth analysis: Need help clarifying a step in the proof that $co D^\ast u(x) = \partial f(x)$

Tags: analysis, proof-explanation, convex-analysis, convex-hulls, non-smooth-analysis

I am reading the book optimization and nonsmooth analysis by Frank.H Clarke and there's a step I'm stuck in the proof of theorem 2.5.1.

So I'll write the definitions first. We work in $\mathcal{R}^n$ We define the upper Clarke derivative $$f^0(x,v) = \limsup_{y\to x, h\to 0^+} \frac{f(y+hv)-f(y)}{h}$$

and we define the Clarke gradient
$$\partial f(x) = \{ p \in \mathcal{R}^n: f^0(x,\theta)\geq \langle p, \theta \rangle \quad \forall \theta \in \mathcal{R}^n\}$$

If $f$ is Lipschitz near $x$, we denote by $\Omega_f$ the set where $f$ is not differentiable near $x$ and we define the set of reachable gradients of $f$ at $x$ as
$$D^\ast f(x) = \{p \in \mathcal{R}^n :p=\lim_{k \to \infty} Df(x_k), x_k \to x, x_k \notin \Omega_f \} $$

So theorem 2.5.1 states that $\partial f(x) = co D^\ast f(x)$ where $co$ is the convex hull, I understand the first part of the proof, what I don't understand is the second part where he shows that the support function of the left hand side is less or equal to the support function of the right hand side, I specifally don't understand what he means with
$$\lim \sup \{\langle Df(y), v \rangle: y \to x, y \notin \Omega_f \} $$

I guess he's taking the limit as $y \to x$ of the sup of the set $\langle Df(y), v \rangle$ when $y \to x$ ? this does't make much sense to me, so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: In this case, it means $\lim_{ \delta \downarrow 0} \sup_{\|y-x\|<\delta, y \notin \Omega_f} \langle \nabla f(y) , v \rangle $. It is the same notation used in defining $f^\circ(x;v)$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for the clarification, with the precise meaning of the limit I managed to understand the proof. If you post this comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: No need :-), glad to be able to help.